# Find an value in mysql with partial matches

Tags: mysql

The MySQL database stores an article called "Be or not Be?".

What should the query be like to find an entry by name without a question mark?

Simple php code for example:

```
$article= "Be or not Be";
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_name=?');
$sth->bind Param(1, $article, PDO:: PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetch();
no matches...
```

Comment: `WHERE 1=LOCATE(?, article_name)`

Comment: Capture the statement before it is sent to the database - with `println` or whatever the syntax is in PHP. Then, try and run it on the MySQL client or in MySQL Workbench - if it runs there, your problem is PHP, if not, it's with the SQL. You could also activate the general log (**on a dev machine**) and see what arrives at the server!

Comment: Can this work for you {select *  FROM articles WHERE article_name=$article}

Comment: Yes, it is works, when $article= "Be or not Be?";

Comment: How to  do make, that only the question mark is not taken into account? Can this be done via regexp?

Comment: I use this:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE REPLACE(article_name, '?', '') LIKE '$article'"; and it works good, but how use regexp?

Answer (score 0):

Update Below Lines : -

```
$article= "Be or not Be";
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_name=?');
```

With

```
$article= "%Be or not Be%";
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_name LIKE ?');
```

Comment: I checked, but your options do not give the expected result, for example, if $article= "Be" then the result is positive, and it is required that it be only if there is no question mark or other special characters, and not parts of the article name.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$article= "Be or not Be%";
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_name LIKE ?');
$sth->bind Param(1, $article, PDO:: PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetch();
```

Comment: I tried it, but if $article= "Be" then the result will also be positive. How to  do make, that only the question mark is not taken into account? Can this be done via regexp?